# BoneCP: Is the getConnection method thread-safe or we have to handle that?

Tags: java, thread-safety, connection-pooling, bonecp

While using the BoneCP connection pooling, I came across the following confusions and would like to hear some advise on this:

- Is the [`getConnection`](http://jolbox.com/bonecp/downloads/site/apidocs/com/jolbox/bonecp/BoneCP.html#getConnection%28%29) method of the BoneCP thread-safe? What is the best way to use this when there are many threads asking for a connection in parallel?
- Is it required to call `connection.close()` every time after using the connection?
- if it is required to call `connection.close()`, will it really disconnect the connection with the DB or just sends the connection to the pool?

Thanks in advance for the support.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `getConnection()` of BoneCP **is thread-safe**; so you don't have to do anything yourself.
And yes, **you need to call `connection.close()`** if you are done with the connection (this is not specific to BoneCP, but applies to any JDBC connection).

As with all connection pools, calling `connection.close()` will return the connection to the connection pool or in some cases also close the physical connection (but really: this is an implementation detail you should not be concerned about).

In general connection pools maintain a pool of physical connections to a database. When you call `getConnection()`, the connection pool looks for an available physical connection and wrap it in a *logical* connection. This logical connection is returned. When you `close()` the logical connection, the connection pool knows the physical connection is available again for reuse.